# How to achieve res "item" with type using gradle resValue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Creating res values via gradle is fine for primitive types such as string, dimen, etc, but i'm struggling to achieve the following using the same code.

The documentation doesnt seem to show an additional options so I think it's not doable.

Example

`<item name="latitude" format="float" type="dimen">56.154439356093</item>`

You cant use `dimen` as the type in the `resValue` call as it creates the tag as `<dimen name...` which is invalid because its a float rather than a dimen.

Is there any way to achieve this via gradle? or is the only way to write the res value as a string then read it out and parse as a float in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like using dimen works fine even without specifying a dimen type (like dp/px) for my specific usecase. Would be nice to have more flexibility with the generic `item` with `format` and `type`

`resValue("dimen", "latitude", "0.0")`